# String.Split only on first separator in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

String.Split is convenient for splitting a string with in multiple part on a delimiter.

How should I go on splitting a string only on the first delimiter. E.g. I've a String

```
"Time: 10:12:12\r\n"
```

And I'd want an array looking like

```
{"Time","10:12:12\r\n"}
```

Comment: split using whitespace? and set an arry = yourString.Split(' ');

Comment: @RamgyBorja that won't work unless he also trims the `:` from `Time` and anyway, not what was asked

Comment: @smurtagh yes, for safe coding used trim

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The best approach depends a little on how flexible you want the parsing to be, with regard to possible extra spaces and such. Check the exact format specifications to see what you need.

```
yourString.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2)
```

Will limit you two 2 substrings. However, this does not trim the space at the beginning of the second string. You could do that in a second operation after the split however.

```
yourString.Split(new char[] { ':', ' ' }, 2,
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Should work, but will break if you're trying to split a header name that contains a space.

```
yourString.Split(new string[] { ": " }, 2,
    StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Will do exactly what you describe, but actually requires the space to be present.

```
yourString.Split(new string[] { ": ", ":" }, 2,
    StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Makes the space optional, but you'd still have to `TrimStart()` in case of more than one space.

To keep the format somewhat flexible, and your code readable, I suggest using the first option:

```
string[] split = yourString.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2);
// Optionally check split.Length here
split[1] = split[1].TrimStart();
```

Comment: Why not use the (String[], Int32, StringSplitOptions) overload? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy.aspx). This only applies to .NET 2.0 and above, but the following gives exactly the result the OP was asking for: yourString.Split(new string[] { ": " }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None)

Comment: @Bernhof: it does. I'm not sure what should happen in case of extra spaces (or no spaces) in the string however. The best approach differs a bit depending on the desired behavior.

Comment: I find it very confusing that something like yourString.Split(':', 2); does not work... Thanks for your explanations!

Comment: `.Select(s=> s.Trim())` is how I often trim the results of Split

Answer (score 14):

In your example above you could split on ": " (i.e. colon with trailing space) as this appears to be what you've done. If you really did split on just the first delimeter you'd see a leading space in your second array element.

However, you should probably look at this overload of Split...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx

```
public string[] Split(
  char[] separator,
  int count
)
```

... which allows you to specify a max number of substrings.

Answer (score 3):

```
?("Time: 10:12:12\r\n").Split(new char[] { ':', ' ' }, 2, 
   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
{Dimensions:[2]}
    [0]: "Time"
    [1]: "10:12:12\r\n"
```

other options:

```
?("Time: 10:12:12\r\n").Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2)
{Dimensions:[2]}
    [0]: "Time"
    [1]: " 10:12:12\r\n"
?("Time: 10:12:12\r\n").Split(new char[] { ':' }, 1)
{Dimensions:[1]}
    [0]: "Time: 10:12:12\r\n"
?("Time: 10:12:12\r\n").Split(new char[] { ':' }, 3)
{Dimensions:[3]}
    [0]: "Time"
    [1]: " 10"
    [2]: "12:12\r\n"
```

Comment: The delimeter is colon, not space. You're right that splitting on space would be fine and give 2 elements, but I don't think that's the question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

I've adopted a variation to Thorarin's answer above,
The below should be able to handle your requirement, plus trim the spaces.

```
yourString.Split(new []{'-'},2).Select(s => s.Trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 5 upwards you can use this:

```
string[] split = yourString.Split(new[] {':'}, 2, StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
```