# C#, an elegant way to split up string at first (and only first) occurence of two or more whitespaces?

Tags: c#, string, split

Is there an elegant way to split up string at first (and only first) occurence of two or more whitespaces ?
Or at least finding the index of this two or more whitespaced string.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is pretty vague. What have you tried so far? More elegant then what?

Comment: For now I had some for loop and bunch of if's. But i thought that there must be simpler way using some Regex methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct an instance instead of using the static method and utilize the overload which restricts the number of splits performed:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s{2,}");

string[] result = regex.Split(input, 2); // only 1 split, two parts
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works but with minor change. 
`Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s{2,}");
regex.Split("AA   5 B C DDD", 2);`
Second argument of method Split() must be 2 insteed of 1.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:
[String.Split only on first separator in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019738/string-split-only-on-first-seperator-in-c)

Or:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx

String.Split(separator, number of strings to return)

Comment: The way I'm doing it now: Regex.Split(line, @"\s{2,}"); It works fine except that I need to split up ONLY at first match.

Comment: that first link won't work well for the problem of unbounded whitespace counts.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex splitting as [shown here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split)

I guess you'd end up with something like this:

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;

Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options); 

string[] operands = Regex.Split(operation, regex);
```