# CSV - Import file to a Sql database through code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I need to load data from text file/csv file to a SQL Server database. I used the code shown below to load data and is loading to the database the problem is the data in second column may contain space but I use space for separate the column data.

i.e.

```
200007 XXXX Check XXXX yyy 50
200013 YYYY Check ZZZZ yyy 50
200022 nnnn 25Mg 30 Tabs
200042 mmmm 30 Mg 30 Tabs
```

I need to store the first ID number in the first column and the remaining text in second column:

```
string str = Properties.Settings.Default.con;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

try
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    cmd.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='TEMP_AUTO' AND xtype='U')" +
                      "CREATE TABLE TEMP_AUTO (" +
                      "ID varChar(10) NULL," +
                      "NAME varChar(50) NULL," +
                      "DATE TIMESTAMP NULL," +
                       ")";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    string query1 = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEMP_AUTO]([ID],[NAME]) VALUES (@num1, @num2)";
    cmd.CommandText = query1;

    string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(txtFilePath.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        string[] items = allLines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num1", items[0]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num2", items[1]);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved your data");
}
finally
{
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: If it is a CSV file, shouldn't the values be separated by commas ? Of is it just a custom text file as the file extension suggests in your code(.text or .txt)?

Comment: The solution is to change the process that creates the text file to use a another seperator (eg tab), or to delimit text with double quotes.

Comment: Agree with @TT. - your underlying problem is that your data contains your separator character, without it being escaped.  Barring some _very_ constrained cases, this makes it ambiguous - it's going to be **wrong** on import (and you probably can't detect it, which is worse).  Fix your generation process first.  You should be able to trigger the bulk insert from C# - you shouldn't need to write this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution might be this:

```
string[] allLines = {
                                    "200007 XXXX Check XXXX yyy 50", 
                                    "200013 YYYY Check ZZZZ yyy 50", 
                                    "200015 ",
                                    "2541111"
                                };

            for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
            {
                string param1 = null;
                string param2 = null;
                int spaceIndex = allLines[i].IndexOf(' ');

                if (spaceIndex > 0)
                {
                    param1 = allLines[i].Substring(0, spaceIndex);

                    if (spaceIndex < allLines[i].Length - 1)
                    {
                        param2 = allLines[i].Substring(spaceIndex + 1, allLines[i].Length-1 - spaceIndex);
                    }                    
                }
                else
                {
                    param1 = allLines[i];
                }

                Console.WriteLine("param1:{0} param2:{1}", param1, param2);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SSIS to map this file as long as it has a standard structure to SQL Table.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one time thing? Have you tried getting the data organized in Excel then using the SSMS import tool to bring it in? If you right click on the Database then Tasks > Import Data the wizard will appear when given the option to choose the source, choose Excel. Flat files is an option but if you can format it in Excel first that tends to work better. [image: Import Wizard]

As you click through you can adjust the column types and where the breaks are, much like importing into Excel itself.

Comment: This is not a onetime thing, need this code to integrate with one working application for data comparison....

Answer (score 0):

Use the String.Split(Char[], Int32) method to split on the first occurrence of ' ' only. Eg

```
string[] items = allLines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
```

Refs: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) and [previous relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019738/string-split-only-on-first-separator-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("txtFile.txt")) // Mention the path,if the file is not in application folder.

   {
            string str = String.Empty;<br/>
            while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] item = str.Split(' ');
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                string query1 = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEMP_AUTO]([ID],[NAME]) VALUES ('" + item[0] + "', '" + item[1]  + "')";
                // Do remain part<br/>
            }
        }
```